# <style> tag inside a <pre> tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress, styles, pre

I'm wondering how to do this. I have this code:

```
// Text
function login_styles() {   
    echo '<style type="text/css">h1 a { background:url('. get_bloginfo("template_directory") .'/images/din_logo.png) no-repeat center top; }</style>';   
}  
add_action('login_head', 'login_styles');
```

This is a function for WordPress theme that should be inside "functions.php". But when i want to insert it to a post to share it on my blog it wont show this: style type="text/css etc. The whole code inside the style tag isn't shown.

To show the code i'm using pre tag inside the post. It seems to be that tags within a tag wont be shown? Why are this happening?

Comment: Are you asking why your blog post is rendering html tags? http://php.net/htmlentities

Comment: Can you paste what the actual html output is, and then what you'd like it to be? I'm having trouble inferring this from your question.

Comment: I expected this to work but doesn't, http://jsfiddle.net/kjDc4/

Comment: @marcuscvj you should just edit your answer to include that output, rather than putting it in a comment, it's very hard to read as a comment

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko the <pre> tag won't stop other tags from being rendered as normal

Answer (score 0):

```
echo htmlentities(..style tag as string goes here..);
```

Answer (score 0):

`<pre>` doesn't stop a tag from being a tag. It just means that white space characters (spaces, new lines, etc) won't be collapsed into a single space.

You need to use an entity or a character reference to express `<` (and some other characters) as *data* instead of markup.

The `htmlspecialchars` function will convert characters with special meaning in HTML (such as `<` meaning "start of tag") to entities that express those characters as data (such as `&lt;` meaning "a less than character").

```
<pre><?php
    echo htmlspecialchars('<style> etc etc </style>');
?></pre>
```

This will give:

```
<pre>&lt;style&gt; etc etc &lt;/style&gt;</pre>
```

Which will **render** as:

```
<style> etc etc </style>
```

Comment: With this code: <pre><?php
function login_styles() { 
    echo htmlspecialchars('<style type="text/css">h1 a { background:url('. get_bloginfo("template_directory") .'/images/din_logo.png) no-repeat center top; }</style>');
}  
add_action('login_head', 'login_styles');
?></pre> it will give me this as output: h1 a { background:url('. get_bloginfo("template_directory") .'/images/din_logo.png) no-repeat center top; }');
}  
add_action('login_head', 'login_styles');
?>

Comment: It looks like your output is identical to the input minus the `<style>` start tag, plus the raw PHP code following the call to the `htmlspecialchars` function. I don't see how that is possible.